# onKeyListener storing value twice

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

I have an edittext called searchOne that has an onKeyListener. What I am trying to accomplish is a way of getting the value in the edittext (which is a search query) and then use it to build a url. I want to do this before the user clicks the search button so I have as little going on in my onClick as possible. I enter a name in the edittext box and click next on the keyboard to go to the next edittext box and the logcat will print:

searchURLOne contains: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=bb0b6d66c2899aefb4d0863b0d37dc4e&query=christopher_guest

searchURLOne contains: http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=bb0b6d66c2899aefb4d0863b0d37dc4e&query=christopher_guesthttp://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=bb0b6d66c2899aefb4d0863b0d37dc4e&query=christopher_guest

As you can see the second and final value of searchURLOne contains the string twice. Any ideas why this is?

```
searchOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //make person search url1
            final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne)); 
            searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.toString();
            Log.d("search1", searchURLOne);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i am having same issue for some reason onKeyListners are called twice

fallow this

[setOnclickListner is initialized twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611125/setonclicklistner-is-initialized-twice/18611258)?

here is what i found on click listners are initialized twice one is for press down event and another one is for key up event so you need to

put in an if condition like bellow:

```
        searchOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //make person search url1
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne)); 
                searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.toString();
                Log.d("search1", searchURLOne); 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction()==0)
        {
            //your code
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```