# setOnclickListner is initialized twice?

Tags: android

```
passCode1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passCode1);

    passCode1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
                 passCode1.requestFocus();
                 }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i have this above code in oncreate method i have kept break points and try to debug i see setOnKeyListner is called or initialized twice.

Comment: can you post your whole codes?

Comment: put a line (return true;) in if condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        passCode1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){  
                 //passCode1.setText(null);
                 passCode1.requestFocus();
                 return true;
                 }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

ADDING KEY EVENT SOLVED THIS ISSUE

WHAT I UNDERSTOOD IS THAT IT IS INITIALIZED TWICE BECAUSE IT HAS TO CREATE FOR BOX KEY DOWN AND KEY UP ACTION

THATS Y I ADDED KEY DOWN CHECK, STILL IT IS INITIALIZED TWICE BUT USED ONLY ONCE

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
passCode1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passCode1);

    passCode1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){  
                 passCode1.requestFocus();
                  return true; // UPDATE HERE
                 }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but that didnt work, Actually Problem is its been initialized twice, is it like while on create its getting initialized once and then it initializes as keyboard loads?

Answer (score 0):

try to return if you get keyListener event inside if loop as below:

> ```
>   @Override
>  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
>     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
>                 System.out.println("Return True.");
>                 return true;
>             } else
>             return false;
>         }
> ```

Comment: Check out my updated answer. Try to put the `return false` in else part it will surely work

Comment: thank you that didnt make much difference, but figured it out, had to add key down event argument check in if condition, that fixed this issue.

Comment: If you have solved your issue then post your answer and close the question.

Comment: i am not able too do that i am getting a message stating that i  haave to wait for 7 hrs